# Different programs are called when using full path and name on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, which

I'm experiencing a strange problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~/Dev/tbb2017_20170226oss$ gcc -dumpversion
5.4.1
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~/Dev/tbb2017_20170226oss$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~/Dev/tbb2017_20170226oss$ /usr/bin/gcc -dumpversion
4.8
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~/Dev/tbb2017_20170226oss$ ll /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  7  2014 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.8*
```

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting different versions???
Thank you!

There is no alias for gcc if that makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe a shell function; try `type -a gcc`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh, `type` reveals gcc *is* aliased to gcc-5. I somehow overlooked it in aliases... Thank you very much for teaching me another useful command and answering the question. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept!